# Freestyle Lines on Wrong Frames

Tags: rendering, animation, freestyle

Basically the character is posed and rendered with various props. At random, suddenly, the lines are "sticking" among multiple frames despite the fact that the object has been moved.

What could be the cause of this, and how can I fix it?

This only started happening recently - I had done many renders with this file / model and suddenly this has started.

The magnifying glass frame is two or three frames down from the hammer one. 
[image: Freestyle lines showing on wrong frames]

Comment: A question with three upvotes but no answer shows great potential!

Comment: Can you provide the .blend or at least screenshots showing the layout? Speculation 1: it has to do with the background. Speculation 2: The hammer is still there but with a unwanted material.

Comment: Is the tool render property (property window) being keyframed to preferably (not render checkbox) ?  Other techniques such as transparent material ... or moved to different layer ... may be less preferable.

Comment: Unless you provide a .blend I doubt this will ever be answered. This sort of problem requires actual troubleshooting to solve.

Comment: Maybe the motion blur is on? It looks like this.

Comment: @1Up Could you add a .blend? (i know it's been requested before)

Comment: I think this might be a bug with freestyle, I think I've seen this problem around before. **EDIT:** Found it http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49118/freestyle-animation-has-delay-in-cycles

Comment: @cegaton This question was asked a year earlier than that one. [Can such questions be called duplicates?](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/49857/2016/12/9)

Comment: @pycoder who knows... maybe the OP was a visionary that could see the future...

Comment: @cegaton I couldn't find anything affirmative on meta about this issue, so I asked a question [here](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2361/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-of-a-future-question). I know this has been asked in [general](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha) before, but that didn't get a clear answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that you might have done:

1. You have Motion Blur switched on as suggested by [Mechanic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/23172/mechanic)
2. You have used a transparent material to hide it.

I can't say anything else if you don't provide the blender file through https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/. With the actual file I would be able to troubleshoot your problem effectively cause I can't see your settings and stuff through the two images.