# Freestyle animation has delay in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

When rendering my scene as an animation, on particular frames (in this instance, 17), I often get a delay in the outlining, like it's trying to outline the next/previous frame.

This doesn't happen when rendering the frame normally - as in not an animation.

It looks like this:
[When animated](https://i.imgur.com/2tXax22.png)

[image]

[When rendered normally](https://i.imgur.com/9FVHo8C.png)

[image]

It's like the actual render is delayed by a frame, but only when animated.
Is this a known bug?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, probably should be reported in the tracker if the issue still happens with the most recent builds

Comment: So........ bug?

Comment: I have had this freestyle "delay" happen when rendering with Motion Blur settings turned on. Is this the case for your project?

Comment: Motion blur was part of the issue, I think

Comment: Similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/29266/28015

Comment: Try to bake your animation with the same framerate as your render. This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 2):

I found using cycles and freestyle so slow (like minutes) that its easier to clone the project file, then replace all the cycle materials for a simple diffuse transparent BI material and run it with BI.  Then composite the frames with the other rendered frames. Of course, I have thousands of polys so it may not help if the model is low poly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your solution? You render only the freestyle part in BI (on a separate render layer?) then composite these frames with the one coming from cycles (without freestyle)?

Comment: Sort of.   I render the blender freestyle with transparent background as .png, then the cycles render completely independent  and composite them in After Effects.  I'm sure you can use Blender to composite them post (I wouldn't know how to tell you where to begin, and I don't think you can render BI, and Cycles simultaneously)

Comment: You can immedeatly combine Internal and Cycles (with compositing). https://urchn.org/post/combining-blender-internal-and-cycles-in-one-render